# Public method for the Shop class called addBuyer(), test not working

Tags: java

I'm writing a method for a Carshop class called addBuyer() that takes three arguments and returns no value. This is my code:

public class Carshop {

```
private Map<String, Buyer> buyers; 

 /**
 * Constructor for objects of class Carshop
 */
public Carshop() {
    buyers = new HashMap<>(); 
}

/**
 * A public instance method that takes three arguments
 */
public void addBuyer(String aReg, String aName, String anAddress) {

buyers.put(aReg, new Buyer(aName, anAddress)); 
}
```

}

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your map gets `<String, String>` but you pass an object as value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues you should work on:

1. You declared a `Map<String, String>` but you try to add an object of `Buyer` to the map. If you want the map to hold `Buyer` objects, modify the map to `Map<String, Buyer>`.
2. You declare the map twice (in the constructor and in your `addBuyer()` method), but these maps are only on method level scope. You should declare the map as a class-level variable and initialize it in the constructor.
3. You should work on your formatting.
4. `private String Buyers`, I think you can omit this once you fixed the other issues.
5. In class `Carshop` the constructor should be `public Carshop()`, this might be a typo or some misunderstanding.

Updated code:

```
public class Carshop {

    private Map<String, Buyer> buyers; // class level variable

     /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Carshop
     */
    public Carshop() {
        buyers = new HashMap<>(); // initializing buyers map
    }

    /**
     * A public instance method that takes three arguments
     */
    public void addBuyer(String aReg, String aName, String anAddress) {
        // here actually add the buyer to the map
        buyers.put(aReg, new Buyer(aName, anAddress)); 
    }
}
```

Following this, you may now add a getter for example so the buyer(s) can be retrieved from the map via the key.

Comment: Yeah, because `addBuyer` is a method of `Carshop`, not a method of `Buyer`.

Answer (score 0):

With `Map<String, String> buyers = new HashMap<>()` you are mapping strings to strings. From your description it seems like you want to map strings to `Buyer` instead.

```
Map<String, Buyer> buyers = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Seems like your constructor for CarShop is not properly named. Should be `public CarShop()` instead of `public Buyers()`.